# Grails 4: "Unable to render errors view" leads to infinite exception loop

Tags: grails

One day the Tomcat `catalina.out` was almost 4 GB in my `Grails 4.0.10` app using gsp views. On examination it turned out that during slightly less than 9 minutes there had been 279 `Unable to render errors view` infinite exception loops, once every 2 seconds, each leading up to a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Each stack trace had some 130.000 lines.

None of my own classes appeared in the stack traces. The app has an `error.gsp` view which is tested.

The app sits behind nginx. I found nothing special in the nginx or Tomcat access logs.

At a loss about this. Any advice?

**EDIT:** I have enabled debug logging in `GrailsExceptionResolver` after examining its source and clues from the stack trace. Hopefully there is more information when/if this problem appears again.

Comment: Something similar happened to me to. Which log file was the stacktrace in? `localhost.${date}.log`, `yourGrailsApp.log` or `catalina.out`

Comment: "At a loss about this.  Any advice?"- There are kind of an endless number of things that could cause a stack overflow while a view is rendering.  Many of those will have to do with how the view is written and what it is doing, and it also could be a bug in the framework.  If you can reproduce the behavior in a shareable app that would make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yeah, the question is somewhat unanswerable, especially on a rainy day. From the absence of advice I gather my problem is not something other people have come across.